# Output JSON is Java so that it can be directly parsed by JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}
```

This JSON object is created is some Java code using the JSON-simple library. What I would like to do is to inject this JSON into some JavaScript via JavaScript's `JSON.parse` function. To do this, I would like the JSON is Java to look like this:

```
"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

I want the output to look exactly like the above. How can I achieve this? Note that the values can themselves contain `"` characters, so they would need to be escaped in such a way that doesn't break the JSON.

To give an example of the final goal:

```
JSON.parse("{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}");
=> Object { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }
```

Comment: Why you wan it to look like this `"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"`?

Comment: So it can be passed directly to `JSON.parse` in JavaScript.

Comment: Can't you do this instead `'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'`?

Comment: @Max , yeah sue, just try it

Comment: Then you need to escape any single quotes in the values. And then, if the values already contained single quotes, you need to unescape these once. Ideally, I want to avoid this issue and have a fool-proof way of doing this.

Comment: You can use this: JSON.parse('{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}'); where you encapsulate the json string with single-quotes. It also works.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-jsonobject-tostring-method-does-not-escape-special-characters/2400) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EscapingExamples).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `JSON.stringify()`. The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string. For more details:**[The JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)**

Comment: I want to go from Java -> JavaScript, not the other way around.

Comment: ok I got now, why to you incorporating an extra stop `JSON.parse`, simple pass the `JSON` to java script??

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove all \r\n from the string that JSON-Simple creates you could simply play with the ' and ". Then you won't need backslashes.

```
JSON.parse('{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}')
```

Comment: That doesn't work directly if the values contain single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to use [JSONObject.quote(String s)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).